# New js in Magento_Checkout into custom theme

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

Is it possible to create a new js file here or do I need to create a new component?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new JS file in `app/design/frontend/{VENDOR}/{THEME}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/` and load it using your preferred method.

See the dev docs here - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html for more info on loading the file.

I say your preferred method as there are many ways of loading JS in Magento 2 and which way is best depends on the context.

Comment: But If I want to create a custom js to changes classes to the select element in form?

Comment: You need to give more info than that sorry, can you update your question with what you need to achieve?